# After copying my Google Spreadsheet that works perfectly, I get openbyid permission errors in both my onOpen and onEdit(event) google script functions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization, user-permissions

I have an original spreadsheet that has both an onOpen and onEdit(event) functions that both use various Spreadsheet.App.openByID(sheet-address) statements, to update data contained in another spreadsheet and it works fine.  No errors.

But if I make a copy this spreadsheet and I'm the owner of all sheets and scripts, even after granting it permissions to the spreadsheets, and updating the sheet addresses, I get an execution error:

Execution failed: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 30, file "Code")

This also happens if I try to use the onEdit function, though the other functions that link to that exact same sheet function fine.

I even have importrange functions that link to the destination sheet, and they work just fine after I granted permissions. The onOpen works when I run it in the script editor, but not when the spreadsheet first opens.

I don't know where else to grant permissions to myself to run a copy of my own sheets.  Please help.

Comment: Related:https://stackoverflow.com/a/29975104/

Comment: Geez!  I forgot to create new triggers for the onEdit command!   Just copying the spreadsheet, and updating the addresses isn't sufficient.  There has to be triggers added to the new copy of the script to trigger on the spreadsheet.

Comment: You're mixing simple triggers (reserved names like `onOpen` and `onEdit`) with things that require installed triggers (accessing any other document). That's a bad practice.

Comment: @tehhowch I'm not sure how else accomplish what I'm doing, which is when a person edits a particular cell of a source spreadsheet (onEdit trigger), the old value is looked up in a separate Query of a master data spreadsheet, and the new value is updated on the master data spreadsheet (Spreadsheet App setValue).  The script then erases what the new value the user typed (setValue) on the source spreadsheet, and the master data for that cell is then read via a transposed (Query) array result, appearing back in the source cell to confirm that the master was updated.

Comment: All my comment is stating is that you should not give a reserved function name (`onEdit`, `onOpen`) to a function that **requires** an installed trigger to have the appropriate authority to execute without error (such as a function that accesses other spreadsheets). So, `function myOnEdit(e)` and not `function onEdit(e)`. You can certainly use the reserved name, but you will then trigger both the installed trigger and the simple trigger.